How can I convert a FFT transform value to UInt8array
I know this question was asked already but I'm currently working with this library. And passing float audio data to the realTransform function. So I'm doing
const f = new FFT(128);
const out = f.createComplexArray();
f.realTransform(out, myChunkOfAudioData);

Then I've asked chat gpt to tell me how I could get the magnitude of the frequency bins and got
  for (let i = 0; i < 128 / 2; i++) {
      const real = out[i * 2];
      const imag = out[i * 2 + 1];
      const magnitude = Math.sqrt(real * real + imag * imag) + epsilon;

I get values like 2.3, 1, 6 even 14 so I'm not pretty sure if that is normal values or if it should range from 0 to 1.
At this moment I'm currently wanting the magnitude to be represented in dBFS in a range from -140 to 0db.
what is the current way to accurately do that also  is there something wrong with my preceding logic?
EDIT
At the end I want to replicate the behavior of this function from the WebAudio Api that convert the fft signal in magnitude from 0 to 255.But as the values from the fft are floats I figured out I need to first convert them into decibels values. Someone pointed me to this documentation so I guess this answers my question but any explanations is welcome.

decibel are a relative measure, as you say you want dBFS, so what's the FS (full scale) in your case?

@MarcusMüller I guess it's -Infinity to 0

no, that's not what a full scale is. What is the range of your input. Do you understand what you want to achieve here? maybe it's worth taking a step back and explaining (by editing) your question what you need that number for.

If you want to scale the max value to 0 dB, divide all bins by the max absolute value and then take the log10 of the magnitude spectrum.

What Baddios said and then multiply by 20 - that is what deci is in decibel. Bel the power ratio and deci =10. Since the FFT is the magnitude you square it and $log(x^2)= 2log(x)$


I'm not pretty sure if that is normal values or if it should range from 0 to 1.

It is indeed normal (but maybe not what you want). I assume that your time domain data is scaled so that the amplitudes are between -1 and +1, so 0dBFS would be equivalent to an amplitude of 1.
The FFT implements the DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform), which has different scaling conventions. The most common convention is to scale the forward transform by 1 and the inverse transform by $1/N$. In this convention the maximum possible frequency domain amplitude is $N$ times the maximum time domain amplitude.
The "best" scaling and definition of 0dB depends a lot on your specific application and what exactly you want to do. Other common options are "symmetric" ($1/\sqrt{N}, 1/\sqrt{N}$) which preserves Parseval's theorem (same energy in time and frequency) or (2/N, 1/2) which make the level of a full scale sine wave 0 dB.

thank you for your answer I'll make tests and see what I get

someone told me on discord to apply 20 * log10( magnitude / N + 1e-7 ) does it seem correct to you? And yes you are correct my time domain data is from -1 to 1. If you could give me the full line of equation in you answer that would be great.Many thanks for your help

My answer is "there are different ways of doing this and it depends on the specific requirements of your application". Since I don't know what you are trying to do I can't give a you "correct" answer, since "correct" depends on your context.

So what I'm actually tring to is fork the behavior of this.This actually perform a fft analysis in realtime but I need to perform it on chunk of datas without having to play the actual sound

@JSmith so, again this is all just scaling. What do you need the scaled values for in the end? We can't tell you what you need without you telling us what you want to do, in the bigger picture.

@MarcusMüller Thank you for your interest, I've updated the question

you only told us what you already told us here in the comment: that you want to emulate some other function. Not what you really need to do! When you actually read the documentation of what that function is to do (and not the mozilla programming guide on how to use that function), you'll see that the function picks its own normalization values. So, please, tell us what you need to achieve with this without referring to a different function that can have arbitrary scaling.

@MarcusMüller I added the detailed documentation with scaling specification also

@JSmith: it looks like the documentation has all the info you need. Why does that not work?

@Hilmar thank you for your interest. I've coded pretty much what was in the documentation an it gives me values that are far too high and a lot of values are clipped to 255.Are you able to debug javascript?
